# Tailwind default text-[color] class not working (rails7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

i've just created a new rails project, setting tailwind as default with the command:

```
rails new project_name -T -d postgresql --css tailwind
```

When trying to use tailwind classes, it work except for the class including a color, like text-red. However text-white is working.

I tried to create my own class using @apply:

```
.red { @apply text-red; }
```

when launching `bin/rails tailwindcss:watch`, i get the following error:
" The `text-red` class does not exist. If `text-red` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive. "

Any idea on why i cannot use this "text-red" class ?

he is my tailwind.config.js (it's the one generated by rails new):

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed as the error suggests, the `text-red` class would not exist with your current Tailwind configuration. By default in Tailwind, the colors that are not  `white`, `black` or the keywords come in shades as listed [in their documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors).

Either use a valid color, like `text-red-500`:

```css
.red { @apply text-red-500; }
```

Or extend the `red` color shades with the special `DEFAULT` key in the Tailwind configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  // …
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // …
      colors: {
        red: {
          DEFAULT: 'red',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Or override the `red` color palette with a non-object value in the Tailwind configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  // …
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // …
      colors: {
        red: 'red',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: It worked, thanks for your answer and for the advise on how to create this class.